# MediaPipe Model retraining for 15 classes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, mediapipe

I am a beginner to ML and am using Google Colab for model training. I am using MediaPipe and I followed the instructions from the 5 classes of flowers example: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/customization/image_classifier. I am successful at retraining this model using the flower set, and can modify this code to detect a green android or pink pig figurine with high accuracy, using only 12 images for each figurine. I can download the model to my Raspberry Pi and apply it on live video from the pi camera.

My goal is to detect a single light when it is on and identify in which position it is located. The light can be in one of 15 positions and I have 6 images for each of the 15 classes, modifying the light condition in the room only. The live feed from the camera is at a fixed position, identical to the position when the sample images were taken, thus I have not done any rotations or other modifications to the images.

Here are a couple of images as an example - [position 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBI9i.jpg) and [position 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSGm3.jpg).

I was expecting this to be an easy classification, but it turns out I have been running into problems. My retrained model has very low accuracy, even when I increase the training epochs to 150 or so, it is still under 25% accurate under training:
Epoch 150/150
33/33 [==============================] - 4s 123ms/step - loss: 2.4801 - accuracy: 0.2273 - val_loss: 3.3785 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
and testing is terrible
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 673ms/step - loss: 2.9110 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Test loss:2.9109785556793213, Test accuracy:0.0

I just don't know how to continue from here. Does anyone have a model that would be better fit for this example application?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.